# How to pass arguments to resolve function in a GraphQL Object?

Tags: arguments, subquery, schema, graphql, resolve

I'm using GraphQL in Javascript, and I'd like to be able to pass arguments to a `resolve()` function in a `GraphQLObjectType`'s field.

Here is the `GraphQLObjectType` declaratio:

```js
export const ModelSchema = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Model',
  description: 'Model information',
  fields: () => ({
    tags: {
      type: TagList,
      description: 'Model\'s UUID',
      async resolve(obj, args) {
        console.log('args', args); // expecting to see an object
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

And here is how I want to query in GraphQLI:

```js
{
  getModels(UUIDs:"0AAAA2EFF6677194ED227EE4AAAA8D4A") {
    total
    models {
      tags (limit: 1) {
        tags {
          UUID
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I want to be able to send parameters (in this case `limit`) to `tags` so when the `resolve()` function is being invoked, I can use this parameter and limit the results, or do something else.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it... Needed to add `args` like so:

```js
export const ModelSchema = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Model',
  description: 'Model information',
  args: {
        limit: {
          type: GraphQLInt,
        },
      },
  fields: () => ({
    tags: {
      type: TagList,
      description: 'Model\'s UUID',
      async resolve(obj, args) {
        console.log('args', args); // expecting to see an object
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

And now it works.